# Devise: custom fields not saved after signing up

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Environment: Rails 4, Devise 3.2.2
Given I added two fields (name, profession) to my devise model.
When I sign up 
**Then I see in the database the new columns not affected.**

Below are my controller and model classes

```
#custom controller
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  #devise's controller extensions

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
       u.permit(:name, :email, :profession, :password, :password_confirmation)
     end
  end
end

#Devise Model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
   attr_accessor :name, :profession
   validates :name, presence: true
   validates_uniqueness_of  :email, :name
end
```

I specify that devise runs correctly and uses my custom controller. 
I also checked in the params hash and it includes the new field values as you can see:

```
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"F3AjMd1/EpYvuhckEMPUkiMZ1szHa6ba7OMbjjSltOk=", "user"=>{"name"=>"test", "email"=>"you@contect.com", "profession"=>"prof", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

And below is the generated sql:

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "updated_at") VALUES  (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 11 Feb 2014 15:14:56 UTC +00:00], ["email", "you@contect.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$Bn3LIldBUDPHKO0vrXd7peVz6q/42hOrCOcqdbvBMHVeEtn4EfKma"], ["updated_at", Tue, 11 Feb 2014 15:14:56 UTC +00:00]]
```

which contains none of new fields added.

Any hint will be welcome, I've been stuck for more than one hour.

Comment: I got the same problem, any one knows why?

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line from your model:

```
attr_accessor :name, :profession
```

This is overriding the accessors already provided by activer record after you migrated your model and added those fields. This is causing them not to be saved to the db.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly now. I was unaware of this fact.

Comment: if remove attr_accessor from model, then form helper can not refer to these attributes.

Comment: @xiaopang that is incorrect. :name and :profession are already fields on that model, no attr_accessor is necessary in this case. Attr_accessor is only used for virtual attribute which these are not.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot I remove the attr_accessor line but keep the access method, then it works